# how to concatenate csv files so each file is added adjacently i.e., to the right, instead of sequentially i.e., to the bottom

Tags: macos, terminal

in other words I am trying to join a few hundred csv files that are 1 column each and I would like each csv file to create a new column instead of creating a new row.

This is the command I'm currently using:

`gls-Mac-Pro:~ gliiiitch$ cat *.csv >merged_files.csv`

Comment: Do you mean you want to add *colums* of data?  Do you have a sample of what you have and a template of what you want the result to be?

Answer (score 2):

Try the `paste` command:

`paste *.csv > merged_files.csv`

You may have to experiment to be sure that the column order matches your expectations...

Comment: thanks for the reply, terminal returned the error "too many open files"

Comment: How many csv files are you working with? Take a look here: https://superuser.com/questions/433746/is-there-a-fix-for-the-too-many-open-files-in-system-error-on-os-x-10-7-1

Comment: I'll check it out.  there are 1,868 files. 230 mb total

Comment: paste worked the number of files is limited to 256. thanks